# can't add cv.h to project

Tags: xcode, opencv

I'm new in Xcode. And i need a help to add lib to my project. I've downloaded opencv framework. I've added it to my project. In main.h i have:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <cv.h> 
#include <highgui.h>

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>   
#import "AppDelegate.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    @autoreleasepool {

    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

}

When i run my project I got an error like this: cv.h not found, highgui.h not found. I check /usr/include via terminal and i saw that cv.h and highgui.h are located there. 
Tell me somebody what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your build settings in xcode. the error message is telling you that xcode does not know where to locate these files. There are two settings you need to update in your xcode build settings.

1. **Library Search Paths**

There are a lot of settings in xcode. To reduce the number of fields you have to search through use the search box in the top right hand corner. If you type in **Library** you will see a section title **search paths** that has the setting **Library Search Paths**. Update that field with the location of your library headers. The most common place is /usr/local/lib.

1. **Header Search Paths**

Just like step 1, you can reduce the number of options xcode displays by using the search box. Search for **Header** and you will see a section labeled **Search Paths** with the option of **Header Search Paths**. Update that field with the location of your library headers.

Comment: Thank you VERY much. But i have a little question also. I found "Header Search Path". When i click it i got "Debug +" and "Release +".   Click "+" and i got "Any Architecture | Any SDK" and type box. Where exactly i have to include the path location?

Comment: via terminal I see libs in /usr/include and in /usr/local/lib i have nothing

Comment: It depends how you installed the library. I use brew for most of my third party libraries which puts them in /usr/local/lib & /usr/local/include. How did you install the library?

Comment: I was following [this instruction](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html#ios-installation). And i have no /usr/local/lib folder. What should i do when i click "Header Search Path" i got "Debug +" and "Release +". Click "+" and i got "Any Architecture | Any SDK" and type box. Where exactly i have to include the path location?

Comment: I don't understand one thing. In /usr/include i have stdio.h. And It's ok, no errors. cv.h is located there too and i can't run my project

Comment: The debug/release reffers to the schema. I would update both. However, looking at the website you sent me you have a framework vs. library. There is a different way to include frameworks. Go into your project settings again.Click on the build phase tab at the top. in the sections "link Binary with libraries" click on the plus sign. Click add other at the bottom left.Navigate to where you have the opencv.framework and select open. do that and you shoudl be fine.

Comment: I've done it before. But i can't see a opencv.framework. I download this framework separately. I've added it by this way...ok, thanks in any case...i'll try to do anything else

Comment: I found same problem. Please help me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619831/openframework-add-addons-in-ios-project-give-error

Answer (score 8):

try

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>

OR

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

For more information about OpenCV installation - [Click Here](https://sites.google.com/site/learningopencv1/installing-opencv)

Comment: I replace stdio.h to /usr/include/opencv. And there is no error with stdio.h. Xcode see this lib perfectly clearly.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
#include <opencv/cv.h> 
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
```

if this still does not work for you try to install opencv with MacPorts. You can find module on this link: https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=opencv

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the installed location for your OpenCV headers is in your user header search path in Xcode.  You can set this either in the project settings or the build settings for your target.